# Collision Event

Tags: java, android, android-studio, collision-detection, collision

I am new to 'Collision Detection'; I have found resources on collisions, such as:

```
Rect rc_img1 = new Rect();
image.getDrawingRect(rc_img1);

Rect rc_img2 = new Rect();
bottomLayout.getDrawingRect(rc_img2);

if (Rect.intersects(rc_img1, rc_img2)){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The image coming from the top of the screen should collide with the layout at the bottom of the screen. When the image hits the bottom layout I want to perform my actions.

Comment: For a more accurate collision detection, search `android pixel perfect collision detection`

Answer (score 0):

For rectangles colliding with other rectangles, you can check all 8 points of the 2 rectangles with .contains() of the other rectangle. More generally, you can use `Area`, and `Area.intersect(otherArea) != null`

Comment: Any chance you could add a small example to your post? I am assuming Area is the first imageView and otherarea is the 2nd ImageView.